# Test case where assert should check the content of the response body

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pytest

I am new to writing a test case.

I am trying to check if the response body has certain value.

Response a power shell script I want to check if that script has the modified values or not.

```
def test_get_script_remotes_auth():
           
    payload = json.dumps("")
    headers = {"Authorization": token, "Accept": "*/*"}
    response_target_api = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)
    assert response_target_api.status_code == 200
```

it is straight forward to check for status code but what i wanted to check is how can i check for content of the body?

Please bare with the trivial question.

Comment: `assert "foo" in response_target_api.text` ?

Comment: @Paolo could this is achieved?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the content of the request by accessing the `text` attribute from your response object, i.e. `response_target_api.text`. If the api returns json, you can even use `response_target_api.json()` instead to get a dictionary

To check whether the values are modified, you would then do:

```py
data = response_target_api.json()
assert expected in data["attribute"]
```

Comment: @qmeenus, i was checking something in line of. 
assert data["attribute"] contains "expected".

Comment: Check the edit, it should answer your question